# How to preserve SQL performance that I get with IQueryable<Entity> with a IQueryable<DTO> when using oData?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-apicontroller

I am using EF Core and oData.  I've noticed that oData "magically" updates my query when my controller returns an IQueryable that returns an EF Core entity, but as soon as I try to return a DTO of that Entity, all data is requested in the SQL query.

Examples:

This API Action:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProjectEntity>> Get()
    {        
        return Ok(_db.Projects);
    }
```

Generates this query:

```
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[EndDate], [s].[StartDate], [p].[CustomerId], [p].[Name]
FROM [ScheduleEvents] AS [s] INNER JOIN [Projects] AS [p] ON [s].[Id] = [p].[Id]
```

but if I return DTO's instead with this Action:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProjectDTO>> Get()
    {
        return Ok(_autoMapper.ProjectTo<ProjectDTO>(_db.Projects));
    }
```

Then the SQL is this:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS bit), [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [p].[CustomerId], [s].[EndDate],
[s].[Id],[p].[Name], [s].[StartDate] FROM [ScheduleEvents] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [Projects] AS [p] ON [s].[Id] = [p].[Id] INNER JOIN [Customers] AS [c]
ON [p].[CustomerId] = [c].[Id]
```

OData magically knows how to add the join only when I use the $Expand syntax when using an Entity as the return type, but with a DTO the joins are made whether or not I requested them.

Is there something I can do in Automapper or oData to get the same SQL behavior with oData for both Entities and DTOs?

Comment: “Magic” generated by AM. It just load all navigation properties that you have mapped.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion

Comment: understood, how can extend that mapping to my DTO optionally the way the EF core does with entities when working with oData.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.ProjectTo` we need to use an additional package: [AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/) that will give us access to the `UseAsDataSource` extension method.

> **[UseAsDataSource](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html#useasdatasource)**
> `UseAsDataSource().For<DTO>()` makes this translation clean by not having to explicitly map expressions. It also calls ProjectTo() for you as well, where applicable.

This changes your implementation to the following:

```
[EnableQuery]
public ActionResult<IQueryable<ProjectDTO>> Get()
{
    return Ok(_db.Projects.UseAsDataSource().For<ProjectDTO>());
}
```

---

Though the question title is not related, the performance issue and reasoning is discussed in these two similar posts:

- [OData accent-insensitive filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71079527/1690217)
- [Automapper ProjectTo maps the subTypes also which not required while using OData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080611/1690217)