# Automapper ProjectTo maps the subTypes also which not required while using OData

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, automapper, ef-core-3.1

I have Implemented ODATA and Automapper and facing 2 problems.

**1 problem:**

If I am using the Data Layer Models, It is giving me correct result:

```
[EnableQuery]
 public IQueryable<Student> GetStudentTest()
 {
   return _studentService.RetrieveStudent();
 }
```

and the expected result is correct where enrollments and Studentaddress is null:

```
studentId : 1
firstName : "Captain"
firMiddleName : "Cool"
lastName : "Marvel"
enrollmentDate : "2021-12-28T06:52:52.743"
enrollments : null
studentAddresses : null
```

But When I use the Automapper and DTO:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<StudentsDTO> GetStudent()
{
 return _mapper.ProjectTo<StudentsDTO>(_studentService.RetrieveStudent());
}
```

The result is wrong that is it gives me result with enrollment and results:

```
[
    {
        "studentId": 1,
        "firstName": "Captain",
        "firMiddleName": "Cool",
        "lastName": "Marvel",
        "enrollmentDate": "2021-12-28T06:52:52.743",
        "enrollments": [
            {
                "enrollmentId": 1,
                "courseId": 1,
                "studentId": 1,
                "grade": 1,
                "course": {
                    "courseId": 1,
                    "title": "Course1",
                    "credits": 5,
                    "enrollments": null
                },
                "student": null
            }
        ],
        "studentAddresses": [
            {
                "addressId": 1,
                "houseNumber": "5/133",
                "city": "Lucknow",
                "state": "UttarPradesh",
                "studentId": 1,
                "students": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**2 Problem:**

Using OData and Automapper with the query like $expand within $expand:

```
/api/v1/GetEnrollments?$expand=Student($expand=StudentAddresses),Course
```

The **ProjectTo** of automapper doesnt able to bind the data to subtypes as mentioned studentAddresses.

The answers and suggestions will be much appreciated.
[odata](/questions/tagged/odata) [automapper](/questions/tagged/automapper)

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData

Comment: Hi I have tried with this But still no luck!.

Comment: Do not close as multiple questions, the listed _problems_ are 2 observable symptoms of the same disease

Answer (score 0):

> I recently wrote about this, though the question is unrelated, the reasoning is the same: [OData accent-insensitive filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71079527/1690217)
>
> **[Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#queryable-extensions)**
> `ProjectTo` must be the last call in the chain. ORMs work with entities, not DTOs. So apply any filtering and sorting on entities and, as the last step, project to DTOs.

The reason that the 2nd example doesn't work is that the data has already been *enumerated* into memory, before the `$expand` clause was applied, calling `$expand` or `Include` on the in-memory collection will not result in any additional call to the database to retrieve the missing data.

Instead we need to use an additional package: [AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/) that will give us access to the `UseAsDataSource` extension method.

> **[UseAsDataSource](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html#useasdatasource)**
> Mapping expressions to one another is a tedious and produces long ugly code.
>
> UseAsDataSource().For() makes this translation clean by not having to explicitly map expressions. It also calls ProjectTo() for you as well, where applicable.

This changes your implementation to the following which should allow the `EnableQueryAttribute` to correctly apply the `QueryOptions` on the request to the underlying `IQueryable<T>` expression.

```
[EnableQuery] 
public IQueryable<StudentsDTO> GetStudent()
{
    return _studentService.RetrieveStudent().UseAsDataSource().For<StudentsDTO>());
}
```

### NOTE:

The implementation of `_studentService.RetrieveStudent()` can still affect this execution, especially the how `$expand` might be applied. If it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` that is simply wrapped in an `IQueryable<T>` using the `[AsQueryable()][3]` extension then the results might not be as you expect, but it would not help to speculate in this post how to resolve this.